# Creating a library with keys for string and float data types from a csv file

Tags: python, arrays, csv, dictionary

I'm new to Python programming and trying to create a dictionary (Data_dict) from a csv file using Python 3.6 in Windows 10.

`data1`

```
A,B,C,D
0.5,0.2,0.3,1.1
0.4,0.3,0.5,0.9
0.2,0.3,0.4,0.8
```

Preferred Keys: predictor_names, predictors, response

Desired output:

```
{'predictor_names': array([column headings], dtype='<U7'),
 'predictors': array([[row 1, columns 1 to 3],
                      [row 2, columns 1 to 3],
                      [row 3, columns 1 to 3]]),
 'response': array([rows 2 to 4, column 4])}
```

Desired Output using `data1`

```
{'predictor_names': array(['A','B','C'], dtype='<U7'),
 'predictors': array([[0.5,0.2,0.3],
                      [0.4,0.3,0.5],
                      [0.2,0.3,0.4]),
 'response': array([1.1, 0.9, 0.8])}
```

Codes:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
with open("data1.csv", "r") as Test1:
    Test1Reader = csv.reader(Test1)
    Test2 = []
    for row in Test1Reader:
        if len(row) != 0:
        Test2 = Test2 + [row]
Test1.close()            
Data_dict = dict()
Data_dict['predictor_names'] = np.array([Test2[0:,0:3]])
Data_dict['predictors'] = np.array([Test2[1:4,0:2]])
Data_dict['response'] = np.array([Test2[:,-1]])
print(Data_dict)
```

Error: 
    `Data_dict['predictor_names'] = np.array([Test2[0:,0:3]])`

```
      TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please don't post images of code or data - post the real thing; a minimal example.  Please read [mcve].

Comment: Do you understand what the exception means?  Do you need to use numpy?

Comment: What are you trying to do

Comment: 1. Sorry for posting image versions of the data/code. I did try putting in the real numbers, but it was messy. Being a beginner to this community, I find posting the data as image as a better alternative.

Comment: Paste the text, highlight it, hit ctrl-K or click the `{}` button.  Not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

`Test2` is a list

```
>>> Test2
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '0.5', '0.2', '0.3', '1.1', '0.4', '0.3', '0.5', '0.9', '0.2', '0.3', '0.4', '0.8']
>>>
```

The way you are trying to index it is wrong

```
>>> Test2[0:,0:3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#205>", line 1, in <module>
    Test2[0:,0:3]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
>>>
```

The column headings are

```
>>> Test2[:3]
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

The `predictors` are

```
>>> Test2[4:7]
['0.5', '0.2', '0.3']
>>> Test2[8:11]
['0.4', '0.3', '0.5']
>>> Test2[12:15]
['0.2', '0.3', '0.4']
```

The `response` is

```
>>> Test2[7::4]
['1.1', '0.9', '0.8']
```

---